# need an explaination for a term in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

There is a term named "API communication" all over around. Can anybody tell me what it is exactly. 
All comments are welcomed here. Thanks

Comment: Without context, this is hardly answerable in a deterministic fashion.

Comment: the term comes from requirements of recruiter from the website. **...The selected candidate ( s ) must have development experience with Mobile UI / UX, Interface Builder ( Xcode ), Objective C, API Communications, and back - end web development.....**

Comment: @ttran - That wording is nonsensical, and reads like the recruiter had no clue what they were writing. Ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> An application programming interface (API) is a source code-based specification intended to be used as an interface by software components to communicate with each other.

[THE COMPLETE ARTICLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)

Even simpler, "API communication" is a way you talk with an application.